# A small discussion about Hatcher Q.1, chapter 0

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, deformation-theory, retraction

The question and its solution are given below:

> [image]

**My question is:**

Should the deleted point of the torus be the intersection point of the two circles? If yes why? and if no, why also?

Comment: You can assume wlog that the deleted point is the intersection of the circles, by deleting the point $first$, and then arranging the square (the circles)  so that the point deleted is the intersection of the longitud and meridian circles.

Comment: The map $f$ from $I^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \partial I^2$ defined by the formula $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$ is defined everywhere except at the origin $x=0$. So the point removed should be the origin, as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not remove the intersection $p$ of the circles $S_l$ (longitude circle) and $S_m$ (meridian circle) because in that case the complement $T \setminus \{p\}$ cannot retract to $S_l \cup S_m$ (a retract $A$ of a space $X$ must be a subset of $X$).

Hatcher's square is the product $I \times I$ with $I = [-1,1]$. He removes te origin $(0,0)$ which after identification of opposite sides *does not* lie on $S_l \cup S_m$.